# Run PHP code collected from database - Without Eval

Tags: php, database, string, wordpress, eval

I want to query a string from my db, which's a `PHP` code and run it. All solutions I've seen on the `Internet` is `eval()`. But I know that `Eval is Evil`.
 So is there any alternative? I've thought of converting my `PHP`code into `data:base64`, and feed it through the `require_once()` function. But couldn't find this successful. Will this way or anything relative to this work? My platform is `Wordpress`.

I've heard people saying storing `PHP` code in database is dangerous. But is it safe to store just raw `HTML` code instead of `PHP` ?

Answer (score 0):

For executing php `eval` is the way to go. And it is not recommended.
It is safe to store html in the database. WordPress does so by itself.
Maybe what you want you can do with a [shortcode](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API). Which is save.

Comment: Thanks. I'll go with storing HTML and apply them as shortcodes later.